TV show with the same premise as Supernatural
What was the name of the old show with two brothers on the road chasing supernatural creatures BUT way before Supernatural?  There were many parallels to the current show Supernatural, even some similar episodes and story arcs (a lot about Satan), but it wasn't as good--poorer quality acting and production values, not nearly as complex.
It was very dark and humorless. 80s or 90s. It's conceivable I saw it 2000-03 but it would have been old already by then. I'm pretty sure it was American but I suppose it could have been Canadian--other shows on that channel were. Not animated. Fairly sure they were brothers, they were close. I don't think the car was anything special and I don't think anyone in it was or became famous.  I don't recall any specific locations--they were all kind of generic and non-specific.  Lots of it took place at night.
I lived in Missoula MT in the 90s and I watched it on a non-mainstream channel in the late afternoon or early evening, so it's hard to pin down the date of the show.
I've done a lot of googling for it, but I must not have guessed the right search terms.  I've been looking under Horror.

Welcome to Movies & TV! What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

Thanks for the extra details. Are you sure they were brothers, BTW? And could it have been from the 2000s?

Fairly sure.  They were close.  It's conceivable I saw it 2000-03 but it would have been old already by then.

Thanks, added. (Thought it was The Immortal, but it doesn't really fit.)

Are u sure it was a show. The closet thing from back in the day people online equate to Supernatural is the Phantasm film series. Two friends (mike and Reggie) that are like brothers driving across america hunting evil. Similar car. Trunk full of weapons. Etc. Other than it being a show your question describes phantasm 2-4

Are you sure it was called Phantasm?  Your description sounds right but I googled "tv series phantasm" and got a lot of stuff about about a series of horror flicks with that name, but they don't have Make and Reggie, monster hunters.  A tv show was planned to follow those up, but it never got made.  There was a Batman movie called Mask of the Phantasm.
